# remote error : repository not found in git

Tags: git, mercurial, google-code

I'm trying to `clone` a local copy of [Hacker's Keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/), througth [Git](http://git-scm.com/), I have tried the `command` :

```
$ git clone https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/
```

but getting `fatal: remote error : repository not found  in git`, and not being to `clone` of that repository, how can I `clone`

Comment: Use http://javaforge.com/project/HGE, to clone `Hacker's Keyboard`, that is simplest way of cloning I have ever experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Hacker's Keyboard project is using [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) as source control management tool, not Git.

Comment: I have eclipse plug in for Mercurial, but how to commit changes to repository?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the link to the repository stored in a .git, or on Github if you are able to find one. If they do not have a repository that is open to the public (that you can get an exact location on the .git), the you probably won't be able to simply clone the repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pure Git can't operate with Mercurial repositories
2. You can use [Bridge support in git for mercurial](http://felipec.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/git-remote-hg-bzr-2/), part of Git 1.9 now